# Is there a way to hide already selected with Mat-select in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to ensure that after a value is selected in a drop down, it should not appear again in the form, also with the second and third

```
// my html 
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>drop down 1</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue1">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let arr of services" [value]="arr">
      {{ arr }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>drop down 2</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue2">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let arr of services">
      <mat-option *ngIf="arr !== selectedValue1" [value]="arr">
        {{ arr }}
      </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>


<mat-form-field class="flex-auto" >
   <mat-select
         [(ngModel)]="selectedValue3">
       <ng-container *ngFor="let arr of arrTmp">
         <mat-option *ngIf="arr !== selectedValue1 && arr !== selectedValue2 && arr !== selectedValue2" [value]="arr.name">
               {{arr.name}}
         </mat-option> 
      </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The problem here is that what i have in the second drop down, appears in the third drop down in spit of the condition statement

````
// your *.ts controller
selectedValue1: string;
selectedValue2: string;
selectedValue3: string;
public services = ['Service 1', 'Service 2', 'Service 3'];```
````

Comment: What do you mean by 'the next drop down'? Do you have another second mat-select or do you want the currently selected option not to be selectable when the user clicks on the drop down a second time?

Comment: yes i have other drop downs where i can also select a next option

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the selected option of drop down 1 from being selectable in drop down 2 by accessing it via the ngModel and decline it on the drop down 2 with ngIf:

```
// your *.html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>drop down 1</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue1">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let arr of services" [value]="arr">
      {{ arr }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>drop down 2</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue2">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let arr of services">
      <mat-option *ngIf="arr !== selectedValue1" [value]="arr">
        {{ arr }}
      </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your controller you will need to have the variables available:

```
// your *.ts controller
selectedValue1: string;
selectedValue2: string;
public services = ['Service 1', 'Service 2', 'Service 3'];
```

[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kanh2c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Oh this makes sense to me, let me give it a shot

Comment: but i tried it for a third one and it does work..using this *ngIf="arr !== selectedValue2 && arr !== selectedValue1" [value]="arr"

Comment: i added a third drop down but it didnt work as expected

Comment: still there? please respond

Comment: Your idea looks correct. What is the error? Does the browser console say something?

Comment: I added a working example on [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ehzbk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template variable reference.
Add a ngModel and a variable to the first mat-select. And then in your second mat-select you can check each spot from the array against this variable. And only show if its not equal.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select ngModel #firstService>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let arr of services" [value]="arr">
      {{ arr }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select ngModel>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let arr of services">
      <mat-option *ngIf="arr !== firstService.value" [value]="arr">
        {{ arr }}
      </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```